# How to get a data from list of list in LINQ?

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have these models:

```
public class StationData
{
    public List<StationToStationModel> Distances { get; set; }
    public List<int> SortestPath { get; set; }
}

public class StationToStationModel
{
    public int FromStation { get; set; }
    public int ToStation { get; set; }
    public int Distance { get; set; }
}
```

In my main page, I call a method that will return an object of type "StationData".

Now, what I want is to get the "ToStation" value where "Distance" is the smallest distance value in the given list of StationToStationModel.  How to do that?

Thanks

RJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
StationData sd = new StationData(); 
var toStation= sd.Distances.Where(row => row.Distance== sd.Distances.Min(r => r.Distance))
                  .Select(row => row.ToStation);
```